# Python JabberBot can't join prosody controlled chat room

Tags: xmpp, prosody-im

I have a XMPP bot written in Python that collects the number of hours logged for each redmine user and then joins a chat room to announce users that did not log within the last X hours  (https://github.com/credil/redmine_jabberbot).

The bot can join uncontrolled chat room.  But for the chat room that have a guest list, it can't seem to join or announce it's message.

- Neither the prosody log or the Python XMPP client prints a warning.
- The bot is in /etc/prosody/sharedgroups.txt .

Here's an excerpt of the prosody log:

```
Mar 14 19:26:34 c2s1492670  debug   Received[c2s]: 
Mar 14 19:26:34 mod_muc debug   room: credil@conference.xmpp.credil.org, current_nick: nil, stanza: 
Mar 14 19:26:34 mod_muc debug   credilbot@xmpp.credil.org/SystemInfoJabberBot joining as credil@conference.xmpp.credil.org/credilbot
```

Answer (score -1):

Two things that made it work here:

1. Editing the `.dat` file in `/var/lib/prosody/$server/config/$chatroom.dat`
2. Restarting the server